# scrapy didn't work well, when it run on aws EC2

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-ec2, scrapy

i make scrapy crawler with motor mongodb for asynchronous work.

so on local env, after crawling, data can locate in local mongodb and mongodb atlas.

but on EC2, when it was running to collect data, crawler kept to stop so i had to press `ctrl + c`. then it passed that task and kept to collect next data.

as a result, this crawler couldn't collect every data. so i had to run it at least 2 times.

i hope this crawler can work well without my fingers.

when task stop i had to press  `ctrl + c`

this is pipelines.py code.

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from pathlib import Path  
env_path = Path('../.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

# import pymongo
import motor.motor_asyncio
import asyncio

# connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://{}:{}@rbscrapycluster.hzuaa.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority".format(os.getenv('ID'), os.getenv('PWD')))
# connection = pymongo.MongoClient()
connection = client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb+srv://{}:{}@rbscrapycluster.hzuaa.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority".format(os.getenv('ID'), os.getenv('PWD')))
# connection = client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient()
db = connection.JeonjuDB

class JeonjueventPipeline:

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
                
        if(item.get('index')) == ' 유관기관 소식 ':
            db.relatedInstitutions.create_index([('link',1)],unique=True)
            async def do_insert():
                result = await db.relatedInstitutions.insert_one(dict(item))
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(do_insert())

        elif(item.get('index')) == ' 새소식 ':
            db.news.create_index([('link',1)],unique=True)
            async def do_insert():
                result = await db.news.insert_one(dict(item))
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(do_insert())
       
        elif(item.get('index')) == ' 공연/행사 ':
            async def do_insert():
                result = await db.events.insert_one(dict(item))
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(do_insert())


        elif(item.get('index')) == ' 주간행사 ':
            db.weeklyEvents.create_index([('link',1)],unique=True)
            async def do_insert():
                result = await db.weeklyEvents.insert_one(dict(item))
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(do_insert())
            
        else:
            print('not valid')

        return item
```

i wonder, why could this crawler work well on local env, but not on EC2.

Comment: What output/error did you get in you EC2 when running spider?

Comment: there is no error. it just looks stop. but sometimes after 20min it work. but usually it just looks stop...@FelixEklöf

Comment: i think, if this crawler can press ```ctrl+c```, when it dosen't work for at least 1min. it can be solved. but i can't fine how to do that :( ...